# Mysql get number of loss users

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join, date-arithmetic

I have a Users table (id, name, created_at) and a Transaction table(id, user_id, created_at, amount).
For each month, I would like to know the number of users who did not have any transaction in the 3 months interval before that month.
For example, for April 2022, the query would return number of users who did not have a transaction in January 2022, February 2022 and March 2022. And so on for every month.

Can I do this with a single MySQL query, and without PHP loop?

If I wanted it for April 2022 only, then I guess this would do the trick:

```
SELECT count(distinct(users.id)) FROM users 
INNER JOIN transactions 
    on users.id = transactions.user_id 
WHERE transactions.user_id NOT IN 
   (SELECT user_id FROM transactions WHERE created_at > "2022-01-01" AND created_at < "2022-04-01" );
```

How to get it for all months?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a normal situation, you would have a calendar table that, for examples, stores all starts of months over a wide period of time, like `calendar(start_of_month)`.

From there on, you can `cross join` the calendar with the users table to generate all possible combinations of months and customers (with respect to the user's creation time). The last step is to check each user/month tuple for transations in the last 3 months.

```
select c.start_of_month, count(*) as cnt_inactive_users
from calendar c
cross join users u 
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from transactions t 
    where t.user_id = u.id 
        and t.created_at >= c.start_of_month - interval 3 month
        and t.created_at <  c.start_of_month
)
where c.start_of_month >= '2021-01-01' and c.start_of_month < '2022-01-01'
group by c.start_of_month
order by c.start_of_month
```

This gives you one row per month that has at least one "inactive" customers,with the corresponding count.

You control the range of months over which the query applies with the `where` clause to the query (as an example, the above gives you all year 2021).

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT count(*) 
FROM users 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM transactions 
    WHERE users.id = transactions.user_id 
      AND created_at > '2022-01-01' AND created_at < '2022-04-01'
    );
```

Comment: I would need this for all months in the table

Comment: @ZvonimirPeran Add months table to query source and replace WHERE in the subquery with according condition.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.